# Why does my Minecraft 1.10 keep crashing right after I hit play?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

```
[20:55:44] [Client thread/INFO]: Setting user: MCAnimate.KDZ
[20:55:46] [Client thread/INFO]: LWJGL Version: 2.9.4
[20:55:46] [Client thread/ERROR]: Couldn't set pixel format
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:585) [1.10.jar:?]
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434) [1.10.jar:?]
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381) [1.10.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124) [1.10.jar:?]
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Why is it breaking :(

Time: 6/17/16 8:55 PM
Description: Initializing game

org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Client thread
Stacktrace:
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:247)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:739)
    at bcx.ap(SourceFile:598)
    at bcx.an(SourceFile:434)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at bcx.a(SourceFile:381)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:124)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.10
    Operating System: Windows 10 (x86) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_91, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 79884784 bytes (76 MB) / 149696512 bytes (142 MB) up to 523501568 bytes (499 MB)
    JVM Flags: 6 total; -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump -Xmx512M -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    Launched Version: 1.10
    LWJGL: 2.9.4
    OpenGL: ~~ERROR~~ RuntimeException: No OpenGL context found in the current thread.
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and client brand is untouched.
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: 
    Current Language: ~~ERROR~~ NullPointerException: null
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    CPU: <unknown>
#@!@# Game crashed! Crash report saved to: #@!@# C:\Users\Family\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\crash-reports\crash-2016-06-17_20.55.47-client.txt
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: Using incremental CMS is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by a display driver issue with lwjgl (minecraft graphics) and it can almost always be fixed by doing the following:

1) Update your graphics card display drivers, then test minecraft again. Info on updating drivers here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/update-drivers-in-windows-10

2) if it still doesn't work then you need to completely uninstall all old versions of Java, then install the newest one only from here: https://java.com/en/download/

Answer (score -2):

try doing what it says in this video.

Comment: While the video may be useful, it is generally best to summarize the key points so in the case the video goes down at a later date, the information is retained.